# how to set up web api on azure without security?

Tags: azure, api

I have a very simple Addresses Controller that works when I host the asp.net web app on IIS Express.

```
public class AddressesController : ApiController
    {
        public int GetAddresses()
        {
            //return db.Addresses.Select(x => x.AddressID);
            return 3;
            //"select AddressID from Addresses";
        }
```

I call the api successfully locally with 
GET https://localhost:44385/api/Addresses,

but I want to be able to call it when the app is hosted on azure.

I published my app using publish, and the index page loads fine.

However, the api endpoint is not accessible.

I verified that Azure's 
"App Service Authentication" is Off for the application. If the authentication is off, shouldn't I be able to directly hit this endpoint?

Response I get is

500 Internal Server Error:
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}

When I try to set breakpoints using the cloud remote debugger, the break points in the HomeController containing the Index Page returns fine.

however, the AddressesController's break point does not get hit. It makes me wonder if creating the controller failed or the routes for the app were not configured properly.

However, when I try to set a breakpoint in route configuration it doesn't get hit when I publish the website (not sure why? maybe the debugger attaches after the website is fully loaded)

edit: thanks to the kind help, I now have more useful error information.

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Addresses'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.\r\n\r\nThe request for 'Addresses' has found the following matching controllers:\r\nWebApplication1.Controllers.AddressesController\r\nRestAPI.Controllers.AddressesController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

the namespace I used was RestAPI.Models. A search doesn't reveal "WebApplication1.Controllers." anywhere in my project. Very strange

Comment: what is the response that you get ? it's OK , 404 Not found or 401...?

Comment: after your update , we need more information to help , can you turn off `customErrors`  in web.config and share with us the full exceptions ? otherwise it's work on local , so you are sure that you publish with the correct publish profile ?

Comment: I didn't know about that. that's good. I will see if I get more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when publishing if the controller has changed and you don't choose 
the "Remove Additional Files at Destination" when publishing to azure.

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3898

Thanks for the help houssem